# How to make Android WebView trust self created root CA

Tags: android, https, webview, android-webview, service-worker

I have created my own `root CA` and added/installed it through `Android` user certificates management menu. I open the associated website with `Android Chrome browser` and I no longer receive message about untrusted/unsecure connection. However if try to open/access the website through `WebView` I see

```
Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

and page does not load. This is resolved by modifying `web view client` :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // this is only for DEV
    }
}
```

But other errors appear and page does not work properly. This is what I see when I inspect `WebView` with `chrome://inspect/#devices`

```
An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

login.html:46 ServiceWorker registration error:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xxx/') with script ('https://xxx/some.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
```